# Code in JMeter JSR223 Sampler comments is executed

Tags: jmeter, comments, execute, jsr223

Please tell me why the code in comments (both /*something*/ and //something) is executed using JSR223 Sampler & BeanShell sampler?
For example, I have:
[image]

and in the next JSR223 Sampler I have:

[image]

and the result is:

[image]

and the question is: why this code: "/*${__setProperty(checkProperty, 50)};*/" is executed regardless of that it is in comment and it is in wrong condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are being executed in the place where they're found, no matter where it is, in [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) label, comments section, sampler body, etc.

Actually inlining JMeter Functions and/or Variables into JSR223 scripts is not the best idea as

- it might conflict with Groovy's [string interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation) syntax
- the function or variable might resolve into something causing script compilation failure or logic error
- and last but not the least [Groovy will cache the first occurrence](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and use it for subsequent iterations

So if you need to set a property - use `props.put()` function like

```
props.put('foo', 'bar')
```

And finally I'm not sure that using `props.clear()` is a good idea because there are some pre-defined JMeter properties (you can check yourself using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter)) and it might result into unexpected behaviour if a test element will be relying on that property existence and/or value

[image]